# Isolated thread pool?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Does TPL have some sort of custom ThreadPool's where I can specify how much threads to use, and of course use Task syntax?

For example, it can be useful to use those as background for 'evil task abortion' (which call Abort() on used thread) calls without caring too much about whether exception of thread abortion is handled or not (cause its used only by you, and not some other framework).

Comment: Aborting threads is going to be around as problematic if you have your own thread pool as it is if you don't.

Comment: And what is so problematic to call Abort() on captured inside task thread?

Comment: You can find lots of information on the topic with a simple web search, although the fact that you refer to it as "evil" implies that you already knew that.

Comment: Well, the problem is, all I can find is "Don't do this! Arghh!", not considering the fact that ASP.NET doing this under the hood and this is main reason they don't hang for eternity on requests.